# How to add a column to an R dataframe flagging activity in other columns?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, conditional-statements

In the reproducible working code shown at the bottom of this post, I'm trying to add a column ("ClassAtSplit", shown in the image below with the header highlighted orange) to the R dataframe that flags the activity in other columns of that dataframe. I could use a series of cumbersome conditionals and offsets like I do in the Excel formula for "ClassAtSplit" shown in the right-most column in the image below labeled "ClassAtSplitFormula", but I am looking for an efficient way to do this in R using something like `dplyr`. Any suggestions for doing this?

I'm not trying to reproduce "ClassAtSplitFormula"! I only included it to show the formulas in "ClassAtSplit" column.

[image]

Reproducible code:

```
library(dplyr)

data <- 
  data.frame(
    Element = c("C","B","D","A","A","A","C","B","B","B"),
    SplitCode = c(0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,2,2)  
  )

data <- data %>% group_by(Element) %>% mutate(PreSplitClass=row_number())
data
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely there is the most efficient way to solve this just in one or two lines but with a `case_when()` you can implement fast and clearly the nested ifelse excel formulas using `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)

data <- 
  data.frame(
    Element = c("C","B","D","A","A","A","C","B","B","B"),
    SplitCode = c(0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,2,2)  
  )

data <- data %>% group_by(Element) %>% mutate(PreSplitClass=row_number()) %>% ungroup()

data %>%
  mutate(ClassAtSplit =
           case_when(
             SplitCode == 0 ~as.integer(0), # This eliminates checking for > 0
             SplitCode > lag(SplitCode) ~ PreSplitClass, # if > previous value
             SplitCode == lag(SplitCode) ~ lag(PreSplitClass) # if equal (0s are avoided)
           )
         )
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 10 × 4
   Element SplitCode PreSplitClass ClassAtSplit
   <chr>       <dbl>         <int>        <int>
 1 C               0             1            0
 2 B               0             1            0
 3 D               0             1            0
 4 A               0             1            0
 5 A               1             2            2
 6 A               1             3            2
 7 C               0             2            0
 8 B               0             2            0
 9 B               2             3            3
10 B               2             4            3
```

If you specify the first case `SplitCode  == 0` then you won't need to check all the time if the values are equal only because they are 0s.

Comment: Very helpful, I am much more proficient in XLS than R so I will be translating a lot of XLS formulas to R, dplyr and case_when seem like easy ways to translate

Comment: Just checking this comment, I made a mistake in the third case_when, it should be `SplitCode == lag(SplitCode)`. I forgot the `lag()`. Edited. @CuriousJorge-user9788072

Comment: Recommend you to check it. Because it there were two rows where SplitCode was greater than 0 but their values were different the previous code would have made a mistake. @CuriousJorge-user9788072

Comment: Hi RobertoT, I concur, it needs to be SplitCode == lag(SplitCode). I noted the error yesterday when running different scenarios.